# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/cisco/jabber/jcf/JGVideoLayout;

Tags: android

I am trying to implement **JabberGuest** SDK to make video calling android app but it fails and shows this error :

```
2019-08-21 11:13:03.042 5424-5424/com.example.mohammadsommakia.visitors E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.mohammadsommakia.visitors, PID: 5424
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/cisco/jabber/jcf/JGVideoLayout;
        at com.cisco.jabber.guest.sdk.jcf.JcfJabberGuestCall.<clinit>(JcfJabberGuestCall.java:71)
        at com.cisco.jabber.guest.sdk.jcf.JcfJabberGuestCall.createInstance(JcfJabberGuestCall.java:506)
        at com.cisco.jabber.guest.sdk.JabberGuestCall.createInstance(JabberGuestCall.java:504)
        at com.example.mohammadsommakia.visitors.appointmentDetail.AppointmentDetailFragment.onCreateView(AppointmentDetailFragment.java:138)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2439)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.cisco.jabber.jcf.JGVideoLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.example.mohammadsommakia.visitors-XYLE74vV6e7y_K2DNTDZNA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.mohammadsommakia.visitors-XYLE74vV6e7y_K2DNTDZNA==/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at com.cisco.jabber.guest.sdk.jcf.JcfJabberGuestCall.<clinit>(JcfJabberGuestCall.java:71) 
        at com.cisco.jabber.guest.sdk.jcf.JcfJabberGuestCall.createInstance(JcfJabberGuestCall.java:506) 
        at com.cisco.jabber.guest.sdk.JabberGuestCall.createInstance(JabberGuestCall.java:504) 
        at com.example.mohammadsommakia.visitors.appointmentDetail.AppointmentDetailFragment.onCreateView(AppointmentDetailFragment.java:138) 
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2439) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852) 
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:733) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

in this line :

```
JabberGuestCall.createInstance(getActivity(), mCallUri);
```

and [this](https://solutionpartner.cisco.com/media/jabber-guest-for-android-sdk-tutorials/jga_tutorial_basic_call.html) is how i implement it

Jabber SDK has a week community and old sdk and i searched everywhere but i have no solution 
please any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NoClassDefFoundError description is, from the SO tag:

> The Java Error thrown if the Java Virtual Machine or a ClassLoader
>   instance tries to load in the definition of a class (as part of a
>   normal method call or as part of creating a new instance using the new
>   expression) and no definition of the class could be found.  The
>   searched-for class definition existed when the currently executing
>   class was compiled, but the definition can no longer be found.

Or better:

> NoClassDefFoundError in Java comes when Java Virtual Machine is not
>   able to find a particular class at runtime which was available during
>   compile time.

from [this](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html) page. Check it, there are some ways to solve the error. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If still there's someone out there dealing with this.
It looks like you are missing the `jcf-release.aar` library which should come together inside the jabberGuestSDK package.